# R - Change value names in data.frame but keeping a distinguishing mark

Tags: r

i have the following data.frame:

```
> goals.names
  id                name
1  1  Registro NL Widget
2  2          Fidelizado
3  3        Entusiasmado
4  4 Registro Newsletter
```

How can I change every id value to look like goal1, goal2, goal3, goal4, goalX? I suppose, that I have to first get the id, save it to a variable, and use it again to substitute it with the new key. Something for what "for each" would really be helpfull, but I have not found a substitute for "for each" in R.

Comment: You could use `paste0('goal', goals.names$id)` or may be use `factor`

Comment: I don't understand why this question was down-voted. To help formulating good questions, can somebody explain this please?

Comment: The question seems correctly formulated, I guess it was downvoted by people who have deemed that the problem was too simple i.e. that the author has been a bit lazy

Comment: @akrun Yes. It's definitelly was too simple, but I didnt know that R can navigate through values with just a function (without a loop). Do you mind writing down an answer to mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try mutate() from the dplyr package, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
goals.names <- mutate(goals.names, id = paste("goal",id,sep=""))
```

Comment: I tried and worked perfect. However, being able to do it with native functions looks like a more optimal option.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use base functions? May I ask why? Package dplyr is a very popular package (mostly because of it's speed and simplicity I guess).

Comment: If you insist on using base functions, you could try transform() instead of mutate(). It does basically the same.